# How do I select the value of a clicked checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have four checkboxes. Based on the checkbox that is checked (or unchecked) I need to `addClass` (or `removeClass`) a css class to any certain divs with class of `filter-result` AND containing a child div with a `class` that matches the value of the checkbox checked. (This is to show/hide search results, so checking/unchecking the boxes will show/hide various search results that have corresponding classes.)

I can write four jquery functions using `id`s that are almost identical except for the `id`s, or I can write one jquery function using variables. I'd prefer to write only one, for obvious reasons. I'm new to jQuery, JavaScript, PHP, etc., so I expect my error is super elementary here.

This is the HTML/PHP:

```
<!-- HTML for the checkboxes -->
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filterBox" value="devotion" id="toggleDevotion" checked/> Devotions
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filterBox" value="blog" id="toggleBlog" checked/> Blog Posts
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filterBox" value="product" id="toggleProduct" checked/> Products
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filterBox" value="program" id="toggleProgram" checked/> Programs
</label>

<!-- HTML/PHP for the wordpress search results -->
<div class="rowSectionInner results-container">
   <?php if (have_posts() && strlen(trim(get_search_query())) != 0 ) { ?>
         <?php while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>
            <?php // Render a separation line. ?>
            <?php if ($hasLoopedOnce) { ?>
            <?php } $hasLoopedOnce = true; ?>
            <?php // Render the search result. ?>
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center filter-result">
               <div class="col-md-7">
                  <article>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                     <div class="siteSearch_date previewDate">
                        <?php echo get_the_date(); ?> <?php echo rename_post_types(get_post_type()); ?>
                     </div>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                  </article>
               </div>
            </div>
         <?php } ?>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery I have written that works, but is super clunky:

```
$('#toggleDevotion').click(function() {
   if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.siteSearch_date:contains("Devotion")').closest('.filter-result').removeClass('remove');
   } else {
      $('.siteSearch_date:contains("Devotion")').closest('.filter-result').addClass('remove');
   }
   if ($(".results-container").children().length == $(".results-container").children(".remove").length) {
      $(".no-results").css("display", "block");
      $("#wrapper").css({"display": "flex", "flex-direction": "column"});
      $("#container").css("flex-grow", "1");
   } else {
      $(".no-results").css("display", "none");
   }
}); 
$('#toggleBlog').click(function() {
   if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.siteSearch_date:contains("Blog")').closest('.filter-result').removeClass('remove');
   } else {
      $('.siteSearch_date:contains("Blog")').closest('.filter-result').addClass('remove');
   }
   if ($(".results-container").children().length == $(".results-container").children(".remove").length) {
      $(".no-results").css("display", "block");
   } else {
      $(".no-results").css("display", "none");
   }
}); 
$('#toggleProduct').click(function() {
   if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.siteSearch_date:contains("Product")').closest('.filter-result').removeClass('remove');
   } else {
      $('.siteSearch_date:contains("Product")').closest('.filter-result').addClass('remove');
   }
   if ($(".results-container").children().length == $(".results-container").children(".remove").length) {
      $(".no-results").css("display", "block");
   } else {
      $(".no-results").css("display", "none");
   }
}); 
$('#toggleProgram').click(function() {
   if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.siteSearch_date:contains("Program")').closest('.filter-result').removeClass('remove');
   } else {
      $('.siteSearch_date:contains("Program")').closest('.filter-result').addClass('remove');
   }
   if ($(".results-container").children().length == $(".results-container").children(".remove").length) {
      $(".no-results").css("display", "block");
   } else {
      $(".no-results").css("display", "none");
   }
});
```

This is the jQuery I have written to try to combine the main show/hide toggle into one function:

```
$(".filterBox").click(function() {  
   var $lemon = $(this).val();

   if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(".siteSearch_date:contains($lemon)").closest('.filter-result').removeClass('remove');
   } else {
      $(".siteSearch_date:contains($lemon)").closest('.filter-result').addClass('remove');
   }
});
```

I expect it to apply or remove `remove` class from divs with class of `.filter-result` - but I get no response whatsoever from anything, including the console. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax for the selector is:

```
$(".siteSearch_date:contains('"+$lemon+"')")
```

Edit---

The following snippet should simulate your code adding a bakground as example, is this what you wanted to achieve?

```js
$(".filterBox").click(function() {  
   var $lemon = $(this).val();

   if( $(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(".siteSearch_date:contains('"+$lemon+"')").closest('.filter-result').removeClass('remove');
   } else {  $(".siteSearch_date:contains('"+$lemon+"')").closest('.filter-result').addClass('remove');
   }
});
```

```css
.remove{
  background-color: red;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filterBox" value="devotion" id="toggleDevotion" checked/> Devotions
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filterBox" value="blog" id="toggleBlog" checked/> Blog Posts
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filterBox" value="product" id="toggleProduct" checked/> Products
</label>
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filterBox" value="program" id="toggleProgram" checked/> Programs
</label>
<div class="row justify-content-md-center filter-result">
               <div class="col-md-7">
                  <article>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                     <div class="siteSearch_date previewDate">
                       product
                     </div>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                  </article>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center filter-result">
               <div class="col-md-7">
                  <article>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                     <div class="siteSearch_date previewDate">
                       blog
                     </div>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                  </article>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center filter-result">
               <div class="col-md-7">
                  <article>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                     <div class="siteSearch_date previewDate">
                       product
                     </div>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                  </article>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center filter-result">
               <div class="col-md-7">
                  <article>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                     <div class="siteSearch_date previewDate">
                       program
                     </div>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                  </article>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-md-center filter-result">
               <div class="col-md-7">
                  <article>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                     <div class="siteSearch_date previewDate">
                       devotion
                     </div>
                     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
                  </article>
               </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any change at all. Still zero change and nothing in the console. The output of `console.log($lemon);` logs the exact word I need, though . . . I just can't seem to get that output into the function.